# Origin of "article" as a grammatical term

Tags: etymology

In English grammar, why is it that *articles* are named so? I associate the word with newspaper *articles*. Where did the term come from?

Comment: Because all the good words were taken.

Comment: What research have you done before coming to ask here?

Comment: Hello, Steven. This might turn into an interesting question for others to investigate—but to avoid having it closed for lack of preliminary effort on your part, and to avoid having answerers replicate the steps you've taken—you should add a brief explanation of the sources you've examined so far, and the information you've already turned up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current definition has five main "*[articles](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/article)*":

> noun
>
> 1.0 A particular item or object:
>   *small household articles*
>   *articles of clothing*
>
> 2.0 A piece of writing included with others in a newspaper, magazine, or other publication:
>   *an article about middle-aged executives*
>
> 3.0 A separate clause or paragraph of a legal document or agreement, typically one outlining a single rule or regulation:
>   *it is an offence under Article 7 of the Treaty*
>
> 4.0 (articles) British A period of training with a firm as a solicitor,
>   architect, surveyor, or accountant:
>   *he is already in articles*
>   *it may be worth taking articles in a specialized firm*
>
> 4.1 The terms on which crew members take service on a ship.
>
> 5.0 Grammar The definite or indefinite article. See also *[determiner](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/determiner#determiner__6)*
>   (sense 2.
>   *ODO*

All of these meanings are connected logically to *joint*, *fit together* in its [etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=article&searchmode=none):

> c. 1200, "*separate parts of anything written*" (such as the statements
>   in the Apostles' Creed, the clauses of a statute or contract),
>   from Old French *article* (13c.),
>   from Latin *articulus*, diminutive of *artus* "*a joint*"
>   (from PIE *ar-tu-, from *ar- "*to fit together*;" (see *[arm](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=arm&allowed_in_frame=0)*
>   (n.1)).
>
> Meaning **extended** to "*a small division*," then **generalized** to "*item,
>   thing*."
>   Older sense preserved in Articles of War "*military regulations*" (1716) and Articles of Confederation (U.S. history).
>   Meaning "*literary composition in a journal, etc.*" (***independent, but
>   part of a larger work***) first recorded 1712.
>   Meaning "piece of property" (clothing, etc.) first attested 1796,
>   originally in rogue's cant.
>
> *Etymonline.com **emphasis** mine*

*Articles* represent a *part* that fits into something bigger:

> - **Personal** *articles* represent *part* of all a person's **property**.
> - **Journal** *articles* represent *part* of the full **publication**.
> - **Legal** *articles* represent *part* of the complete **document**.
> - **Employment** *articles* represent *part* of the work **arrangement**.
> - **Grammatical** *articles* represent *part* of the noun **phrase**.

Grammatical *articles* have no meaning by themselves, but obtain meaning as *part* of their noun phrase. From *[Dissertations Moral and Critical](https://books.google.com/books?id=PrBDAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA187&dq=%22the%20article%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=9NRGVZrsC4eqgwS334DwAQ&ved=0CBwQ6AEwADge#v=snippet&q=%22the%20article%22&f=false)*, Volume 1, by ames Beattie in 1788:

> A single word may convey the full import of a sentence. And this may
>   happen in every part of speech ; the **article** and conjunction excepted,
>   which **can never stand by themselves**, because **they have no meaning ,
>   unless when they are joined with other words**.

The **grammatical** *article* also presents a noun as a *part* of a larger class of items:

> - **fish** is a noun representing a **class**.
> - **a fish** is an indefinite noun which is *part* of the **class** fish
> - **the fish** is a definite noun which is *part* of the **class** fish

Comment: None of which appears to address the question.

Answer (score 11):

The first sense of *article* is "a separate portion of something written." - *OED*

This sense is the basis of most other meanings of article including the grammatical article. Grammatical article is defined in *OED* as:

> Each of the members of a small set of words  that give definiteness or indefiniteness and specificness or genericness to the application of a noun

As we covered the definition part, *OED* mentions that their etymon is  classical Latin *articulus*:

> joint, limb, finger, subdivision, part, point of time, juncture, critical moment, clause or section, pronoun or pronominal adjective, (definite or indefinite) article, in post-classical Latin also a multiple of ten (from 8th cent. in British sources) < **artus** joint ( < an Indo-European base with the sense ‘to join’ which also ultimately underlies arm n.<sup>1</sup>, art n.<sup>1</sup>) + ***-culus*** -cle suffix.

*OED* adds that the grammatical article was in Latin use after ancient Greek *ἄρθρον* and gives the following explanation:

> For the ancient Stoic grammarians the term *ἄρθρα* embraced both articles and pronouns, but they differentiated two categories, calling articles *ἄρθρα ἀοριστώδη* ‘indefinite joining words’ and pronouns *ἄρθρα ὡρισμένα* ‘definite joining words’. By the time of Apollonius Dyscolus (2nd cent. a.d.) the article and the pronoun had been classified as two separate parts of speech and designated *ἄρθρον* and *ἀντωνυμία* respectively. Correspondingly the Latin grammarians (from the time of Quintilian (1st cent. a.d.)) used *articulus* for article and *pronomen* for pronoun. Latin had no articles as such, and Greek had only a definite article (*ὁ , ἡ , τό* the adj.). The distinction between ‘definite’ (e.g. the ) and ‘indefinite’ (e.g. a ) articles arose in the context of the description of modern Romance languages, though the terms go back ultimately (via Latin) to the Greek terms mentioned above.  The English terms appear to be unknown to Palsgrave (1530) though he distinguishes two articles in French, *ung* and *le* (without giving them specific names).

According to *OED*, the word *article* (for the grammatical sense) first appears in D. Thomson's *Middle Eng. Grammatical Texts* (c1400):

> Þat is a nown þat declines w<sup>t</sup> **artikyls** and case or w<sup>t</sup> thre diueris endyngys in a case.

Comment: So the Latin grammarians did not use articulus to refer to any Latin words, but only to the Greek definite article?

Comment: @sumelic: Latin needed a word for that part of speech in Greek so that GSL teachers could explain to their students what these words were (no analogs of which existed in Latin).

Comment: +1 I find this answer more satisfying than my own :-) I'm not sure why I didn't think of the Greek ἄρθρον.